# Create file.desktop on ubuntu for a Qt GUI Script

Tags: ubuntu, icons, python3, qt, pyqt

I have a simple GUI script written in python3 ,Qt5.
in folder of project exist an icon folder that are contain icons used in app.I created a app.desktop file in "/usr/share/applications/" :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PyBrowser
Comment=simple browser written pyqt5
Exec=/opt/pybrowser/main.py
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/browser-icon.png
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
StartupNotify=true
```

now when I run app from application menu , i can see no icon used on app

also:

```
chmod 777 -R /opt/pybrowser

sauron@com$ ls -ltrh pybrowser
total 8.0K
drwxrwxrwx 2 sauron sauron 4.0K Nov 22 22:50 icons
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sauron sauron 2.9K Jan 30 18:24 main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to give the full path of the photos on python script. for example:
'/opt/pybrowser/icons/tasvir.ico' is correct.but
'icons/tasvir.ico' is mistake